# QML Local Storage Can't assign to existing role of different type in boolean variable?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm making an application on Qt Creator. I have a ToolButton like this:

```
ToolButton {
    icon.source: (star) ? "icons/star.svg" : "icons/star-border.svg"
    onClicked: {
        star = !star
        Data.update(number, star)
    }
    states: State {
        name: "pressed"; when: parent.pressed === true
        PropertyChanges { target: parent; icon.source: (star) ? "icons/star.svg" : "icons/star-border.svg" }
    }
    transitions: Transition {
        from: ""
        to: "pressed"
        reversible: true
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected, but when the ToolButton is clicked this error appears on Application Output:

> Unknown File: Can't assign to existing role 'star' of different type
>   [Bool -> Number]

It looks like  this line is the causing the error: `star = !star`
where `star` variable is boolean from database (Local Storage).

Is it important to fix it?

How to fix it?

Is this the right approach to change `icon.source onClick` ???

Comment: what is Data, provide a [mcve]

Comment: what is `star` here?

Comment: Where has star defined?

Comment: Local Storage uses SQLite, and in SQLite there is no boolean, so the Boolean variable is mapped to 0 or 1. It generates that error for you

Comment: change `star = !star` to `star = star ? 0: 1`

Comment: @eyllanesc that's the fix, post it as answer so I can choose it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Storage uses SQLite, and in SQLite there is no boolean, so the Boolean variable is mapped to 0 or 1.

For what a workaround is to replace:

```
star = !star
```

by

```
star = star ? 0: 1
```